# Would I be able to use LED bulbs with these fixtures that only say incandescent?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, led, light-bulb

I’m sure the answer is yes I can, but is it safe and will the life of the LED hold up?

https://www.lowes.com/pd/Z-Lite-Lagoon-15-in-Matte-Black-Transitional-Flush-Mount-Light/1002825630

https://www.lowes.com/pd/Quoizel-Blanche-4-Light-Matte-Black-Semi-Flush-Mount/5001646779

Comment: I can't see the links, but think they do not want you to use halogen bulbs.  LEDs do want some ventilation to remove heat, so if the fixtures are sealed, LEDs might heat up too much and have a short lifespan.

Comment: There should be no issues with using LED equivalent bulbs that are rated lower in power than 60W.

Comment: Agree with comments above, (especially the unenclosed one), but you can always contact the manufacturer to verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LEDs should be perfectly fine. However, you want to match the *lumens* and not the *Watts*. For example, the Z-Lite (first link) is listed as:

- A19 shape
- E26 base
- 800 lumens
- 100W

The 800 lumens is the *typical* amount of light. A19 and E26 are generally absolutes - wrong size and/or shape and the bulb won't fit properly. 100W is the *maximum* amount of power, usually based on heat dissipation. A typical 60W incandescent bulb will produce 800 lumens and a typical 100W incandescent bulb will produce ~ 1,500 lumens.

Putting in these factors (except 100W) for LED bulbs into Lowes web site (since that's where the fixtures are from) the first result is a pack of [GE bulbs](https://www.lowes.com/pd/GE-Relax-60-Watt-EQ-A19-Soft-White-Dimmable-LED-Light-Bulb-8-Pack/1000444903) that are A19, E26, 800 lumens and only **8.5 Watts**. Those (and anything similar) should work just fine. Bumping up a bit to something [like this GE](https://www.lowes.com/pd/GE-Refresh-100-Watt-EQ-A21-Daylight-Dimmable-LED-Light-Bulb-2-Pack/5002210781) gets you 1,600 lumens for 13.5 Watts, roughly equivalent to what you would get from a typical 100W incandescent bulb. A bit larger **should** be OK but I wouldn't recommend it because:

- While total heat generated by LED bulbs is far less than equivalent (based on lumens) incandescent bulbs, the heat generated is much more concentrated in the base than it is with an incandescent bulb, and that can cause problems.
- If the fixture is designed for a range of 800 lumens (stated) to 1,700 lumens (based on 100W incandescent max.) and you put in 3,000 lumens of LED lighting (perhaps 25W) it will likely be too bright for the design. These types of fixtures are more than just a bare bulb socket, and are designed to look good (though that is subjective) with a particular amount of light.

Comment: Another reason (with respect to your penultimate bullet point) is that LED bulbs are far more sensitive to heat - they're electronic devices, while incandescent bulbs are just metal and glass, designed so that a bit of metal gets white hot

Comment: LED bulbs will often have warnings not to use them in completely enclosed fixtures. (Maybe this is less common for newer or more expensive bulbs?) If they say that, you should expect them to have a shorter lifetime due to heat build-up if used in that first fixture, unless it has openings for venting heat inside into the ceiling or something.